# Interactions of Show and PlotRange for ListLogPlot

Tags: plotting

Doing some Log plots and seeing odd interactions with Show and PlotRange

Simple example

```
ListLogPlot[{Range[100], Range[100]^2}\[Transpose]];
Show[%, PlotRange -> {1, 5}];
Grid[{{%%, %}}]
```

I would have expected the plot range on the righthand plot to be (1,5) not (Exp(1), Exp(5))

Is this expected? If so it seems wrong to me.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is somehow expected. The result of `ListLogPlot` is a `Graphics`:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[100], Range[100]^2}]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, ...} *)

plot = ListLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 10}}];

plot // InputForm
(* Graphics[..., 
     Point[{{1., 0.}, {2., 1.3862943611198906}, 
            {3., 2.1972245773362196}, {4., 2.772588722239781}, 
            {5., 3.2188758248682006}, {6., 3.58351893845611} ...},
     PlotRange -> {{1., 100.}, {0., 2.302585092994046}}, ...] *)
```

`Graphics` uses the regular cartesian coordinates, and it was a `ListLogPlot`'s job to convert your data points and `PlotRange` to the log scale, which you can see by observing the coordinates inside `Point` and the resulting `PlotRange`.

Therefore, when you alter the `PlotRange` within `Show`, you are not working in the original coordinate system of your data anymore, but in this transformed one.